# how to stop UIAccelerometer?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented application in which there is one speedo meter and three buttons.
1)Start 2)stop 3)review
When i press the start button than UIAccelerometer is start
when i press stop button than UIAccelerometer is stop.
when i press review button than in next view it will show hisry of time.

My problem is that:
When i press the start button than apliuction is terminated.
how to start and stop UIAccelerometer ??

Answer (score 8):

Use this to start the accelerometer measurement via delegate method *accelerometer:didAccelerate:*

```
[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = self;
```

And this to stop it

```
[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer].delegate = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

To "start" and "stop" accelerometer (i.e. to register and ignore the accelerometer inputs), set the UIAccelerometer delegate to the class which will use the data (on start) or set the delegate to nil (to stop). If you set the delegate to nil, the accelerometer data will not be used by your app.

In case the issue is something else (an error in your code etc), please post what you have tried till now and you'll get more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the UIAccelerometer code and then try start, stop, review, and start to see if it still crashes.